# Characterizing iptables impact

Tags: iptables, performance

Circumstances force us to open a port to the internet and we want to set up a "white list" of IP ranges that are allowed to access that port. I have prototyped the solution so I understand the implementation. There is concern over the impact of having a large white-list (5000 ranges). Is there any way to characterize the performance impact of such a rule set? How can you get metrics out of iptables?

Comment: iptables filtering runs in kernel mode, so it's best of best that your CPU can provide. I did not had a table with 5000 entries, but 500+ entries runs fine on a decent AMD CPU.

Comment: If you haven't, you should take a look at [ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/), which allows creating (possibly complex) sets of ip addresses. You can then refer to an ipset from iptables. This is in my opinion much more easier to maintain than separate rules in iptables.

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/75959 and http://www.slideshare.net/brouer/netfilter-making-large-iptables-rulesets-scale

Comment: "ipset" looks intriguing. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Ipsets are awesome!

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/75368/how-many-instructions-can-be-stuffed-into-iptables-without-loosing-system-sanity and https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/advanced-firewall-configurations-ipset

Answer (score 2):

A recent Core cpu should be able to handle this fine.

However, it still doesn't hurt to see whether the rules can be optimized. One thing that can help depending on the dostribution of the IP addresses is to split up the rules into e.g. 8 parts:

```
iptables -N ourtable
iptables -N ourtable-000
iptables -N ourtable-032
iptables -N ourtable-064
iptables -N ourtable-096
iptables -N ourtable-128
iptables -N ourtable-160
iptables -N ourtable-192
iptables -N ourtable-224

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12345 -j ourtable
iptables -A ourtable -s   0.0.0.0/3 -j ourtable-000
iptables -A ourtable -s  32.0.0.0/3 -j ourtable-032
iptables -A ourtable -s  64.0.0.0/3 -j ourtable-064
iptables -A ourtable -s  96.0.0.0/3 -j ourtable-096
iptables -A ourtable -s 128.0.0.0/3 -j ourtable-128
iptables -A ourtable -s 160.0.0.0/3 -j ourtable-160
iptables -A ourtable -s 192.0.0.0/3 -j ourtable-192
iptables -A ourtable -s 224.0.0.0/3 -j ourtable-224

iptables -A ourtable-000 -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
...
iptables -A ourtable-000 -j DROP

iptables -A ourtable-032 -s 32.1.2.3 -j ACCEPT
...
iptables -A ourtable-032 -j DROP

# etc...
```

This way a packet will be checked against 625 rules instead of 5000 (assuming of course an even distribution of addresses, which is probably not the case; you can tune the splitting of the whole address space accordingly).

I'm also assuming you already have subnets in your list (i.e. if you need to allow 172.18.0.0 up to 172.18.0.7, you replace that with 172.18.0.0/29). If not, check for such ranges. On Debian I use the `netmask` utility to see what a given netmask covers:

```
$ $ netmask -r 172.18.0.0/29
 172.18.0.0-172.18.0.7      (8)
```